# Android getActionBar vs getSupportActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

    //android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setTitle("Android");

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Droid");
}
```

While using the getSupportActionBar() my app runs just fine with kitkat and other new versions but using getActionBar results into an error.

Here is error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
            at com.github.domain.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372
```

Why? From android documentations :

> Caution: Be certain you import the ActionBar class (and related APIs)
> from the appropriate package:
>
> If supporting API levels lower than 11:
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
>
> If supporting only API level
> 11 and higher:  import android.app.ActionBar

Now why this app is crashing?

Comment: if you are using support library you should relay on `getSupportActionBar()` method. What android version are you using for testing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat you always have to call `getSupportActionBar()` no matter which Android Version your App is running.

Which Android versions do you target?

I would advise you to use the new [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of ActionBar, because it's way more flexible to use.

Comment: No, I am not using AppCompat. I am testing my app on Android 4.4.4. I will look into Toolbar but I want to know reason for this error.

Comment: alright, if you're importing the SupportActionBar you always have to call `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: I just saw that AppCompat  is used in styles.xml. So, is this the issue?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: yep, thats the issue. You can access the AppCompat ActionBar with `getSupportActionBar()` and everything is fine. You don't have to check the Android version in this case.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestion that which should be used keeping compatibility and other factors in mind?

Comment: AppCompat is the correct choise to keep the compatibility. The SupportLibrary takes care of the ActionBar for you, you can see the different features of the SupportLibs [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) .

Answer (score 5):

If you are extending `AppCompatActivity` then you are providing backward support for older Android versions and for that you have to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

If you are importing *`android.app.ActionBar`* then you have to use `getActionBar()` and if you are importing *`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`* then you have to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

**Note:** By using *`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`*, you can provide backward support for older Android versions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was at loss about `getActionBar` (producing `null`) and  `getActionBar` (working correctly). My app contains `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` - it has been created automatyically, not by myself. I see in comments and answer that `ActionBar` is obsolete and being replaced with `ToolBar`. Is it worth move my app (being developed) to new technology?

Comment: @Spectorsky It is always worth to remove deprecated/obsolete code and migrate to latest implementation whenever **feasible**! You will be safe when that code is totally removed from SDKs in future. :)

Comment: thanks for reply! What should be done (in general) to migrate from `ActionBar` to `ToolBar`? I don't intent to use toolbar exepting menu (if it is in toolbar) and back button.

Comment: @Spectorsky this may help: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up