# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am working on a Fragment Activity which contains some tabs.While running the code ,i am getting null object reference problem .Code is given below.

**1. ActivityProfessionalTimeline.java**

```
public class Activity_ProfessionalTimeline extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, OnClickListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private TextView mtext_FirstTab;
private TextView mtext_SecondTab;

private TextView mtext_ThirdTab;
private TextView mtext_FourthTab;

private ImageView _img_Profile;

private TextView _txt_UserName;
private TextView _txt_UserDestination;

ArrayList<Model_LoginDetails> arr_LogInUserDetails = new ArrayList<Model_LoginDetails>();

private ImageView _imt_userImage;
private ListView _listView_SelectOpition;

private boolean profilebtnstatus = false;
private RelativeLayout _relativelayour_status;
private ListView _listviewmoroption;
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_professionalttimeline);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    arr_LogInUserDetails = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");

    _imt_userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imt_userImage);
    _txt_UserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_UserName);
    _txt_UserDestination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Userdestination);

    _img_Profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_Profile);
    _listviewmoroption = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewmoroption);
    _listviewmoroption.setAdapter(new Adapter_MenuOpition(
            Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this));
    _listviewmoroption.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            switch (arg2) {
                case 0:
                    fun_hidemenu();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Intent int_ProfessionalTimeline = new Intent(
                            Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this,
                            Acitivty_AccountSetting.class);
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist",
                            arr_LogInUserDetails);
                    int_ProfessionalTimeline.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(int_ProfessionalTimeline);
                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:
                    finish();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    _relativelayour_status = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.reltv_Menu);

    _listView_SelectOpition = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_allSelection);
    _listView_SelectOpition.setAdapter(new Adapter_SelectionOpition(
            Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this));
    _listView_SelectOpition
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    switch (arg2) {
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent int_Intership = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_InterShip.class);
                            int_Intership.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_Intership);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Intent int_AddJob = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_AddJob.class);
                            int_AddJob.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            int_AddJob.putExtra("addjob", "addJob");
                            startActivity(int_AddJob);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Intent int_SearchJob = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_SearchJob.class);
                            int_SearchJob.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_SearchJob);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Intent int_PostedJob = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_PostedJob.class);
                            int_PostedJob.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_PostedJob);
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            Intent int_AppliedJob = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, TabFragment_AppliedJob.class);
                            int_AppliedJob.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_AppliedJob);
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            Intent int_JobMENTOR = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_JobMentor.class);
                            int_JobMENTOR.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_JobMENTOR);

                            break;

                        case 7:
                            Intent int_JobMEtees = new Intent(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this, Tab_mentees.class);
                            int_JobMEtees.putExtra("image", arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url());
                            startActivity(int_JobMEtees);
                            break;

                        case 8:

                            break;

                        case 9:

                            break;

                        case 10:

                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

    _img_Profile.setOnClickListener(this);

    Picasso.with(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this)
            .load(arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url())
            .into(_imt_userImage);
    _txt_UserName.setText(arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getUser_Name());
    _txt_UserDestination.setText(arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0)
            .getUser_Skills());

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    // actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    // actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#fbae38")));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#2b4d72")));
    // actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
    View actionBarView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom_layout,
            null);
    ImageView _mProfileImage = (ImageView) actionBarView
            .findViewById(R.id.img_Profile);
    Picasso.with(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this)
            .load(arr_LogInUserDetails.get(0).getThumbnail_url())
            .into(_mProfileImage);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarView);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            arr_LogInUserDetails, Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Adding First Tabs
    mtext_FirstTab = new TextView(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this);
    mtext_FirstTab.setText("Social");
    mtext_FirstTab.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
    mtext_FirstTab.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mtext_FirstTab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbae38"));
    mtext_FirstTab.setTextSize(12);

    mtext_FirstTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.social, 0, 0, 0);
    mtext_FirstTab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mtext_FirstTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final Tab firstTab = actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(mtext_FirstTab);
    firstTab.setTabListener(this);

    // Add Second Tab
    mtext_SecondTab = new TextView(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this);
    mtext_SecondTab.setText("Professional");
    mtext_SecondTab.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
    mtext_SecondTab.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mtext_SecondTab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbae38"));
    mtext_SecondTab.setTextSize(12);
    mtext_SecondTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.professional, 0, 0, 0);
    mtext_SecondTab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mtext_SecondTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final Tab SecondTab = actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(mtext_SecondTab);
    SecondTab.setTabListener(this);

    // AddThirdTab
    mtext_ThirdTab = new TextView(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this);
    mtext_ThirdTab.setText("Shop");
    mtext_ThirdTab.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
    mtext_ThirdTab.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mtext_ThirdTab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbae38"));
    mtext_ThirdTab.setTextSize(12);
    mtext_ThirdTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.shop,
            0, 0, 0);
    mtext_ThirdTab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mtext_ThirdTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final Tab ThirdTab = actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(mtext_ThirdTab);
    ThirdTab.setTabListener(this);

    // AddFourthTab
    mtext_FourthTab = new TextView(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.this);
    mtext_FourthTab.setText("Blog");
    mtext_FourthTab.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
    mtext_FourthTab.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mtext_FourthTab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbae38"));
    mtext_FourthTab.setTextSize(12);
    mtext_FourthTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.blog, 0, 0, 0);
    mtext_FourthTab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mtext_FourthTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final Tab FourthTab = actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(mtext_FourthTab);
    FourthTab.setTabListener(this);

    Tab[] arr = {firstTab, SecondTab, ThirdTab, FourthTab};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(arr[i]);
    }
    // for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    // actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
    // .setTabListener(this));
    // }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            fun_hidemenu();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    fun_hidemenu();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.img_Profile:
            if (profilebtnstatus == false) {
                _relativelayour_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                _img_Profile.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#faad38"));
                profilebtnstatus = true;
            } else {
                fun_hidemenu();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void fun_hidemenu() {
    if (profilebtnstatus == true) {
        _relativelayour_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _img_Profile.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2b4d72"));
        profilebtnstatus = false;
    }

}
```

}

**2.logcat**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.sevenhorse.almabay.Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.onCreate(Activity_ProfessionalTimeline.java:210)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: use getSupportActionBar(); instead of using getActionBar();

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing `android.app.ActionBar` then you have to use `getActionBar()` and if you are importing `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` then you to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

For more info refer [Android getActionBar vs getSupportActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002209/android-getactionbar-vs-getsupportactionbar)

Comment: Fixed the issue .I have done the following changes:                                       1.) I used AppCompatActivity in place of FragmentActivity                                2.)  Added  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  in styles.xml                                                                                                                3.) Used getSupportActionBar() in place of getActionBar() .