# Cannot create tabs in action bar using ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I am absolute beginner to Android. I am about to create action bar with tabs. But my Android SDK version is too low. So I tried to use old way of creating action bar with tabs using ActionBarActivity. I want to know both old and new ways as well. Now I doing like this.

My activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for(int i = 1;i<=3;i++){
            ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab" + i);
            bar.addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

But when I run my app. It is throwing error. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show us the logcat rror

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Use `AppCompactActivity` with `ToolBar`.

Comment: I want to know the old way as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `ActionBarActivity` since it is deprecated.

**And you are using:**

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

with : `ActionBarActivity`

Change it to `AppCompatActivity` in your java codes(`Activity`).

This should solve the problem. and of course if you are using `AppCompat`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarmain);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

similiar questions:

[Android getActionBar vs getSupportActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002209/android-getactionbar-vs-getsupportactionbar)

Comment: My current SDK is too low.

Comment: yes. I did it. Before i did not event know how to update it. I am absolute beginner. :)

Comment: Is that backward-compatible ?

Comment: Yeah, if you mean you can use AppCompat for previous APIs yes.

Comment: For low Android version like 4.2.2 ?