# SupportActionBar: How to change the title?

Tags: android, appbar

This Layout came from a Studio 3.5.1 template. I can't figure it out. But my question hopefully has an easy answer.

Here is the XML layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ChecklistActivity">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabAppBarLayout"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my app Activity (Java), I would like to change the `android:label="@string/app_name` text (specified in the Activity  Manifest) as it appears on the Activity header (appBar, toolBar, whatever it is). I have not been able to do that as of yet.

[image: Screenshot of AppBar with tilte]

Comment: I would like to put a timer "(hhh:mm)" in that label that updates every minute. I know how to write the timer code. Is this not appropriate? Better options?

Comment: Thanks for the input Richard, does it matter 'why' I want to change that label? That label is different for each activity as defined in the Manifest. I want to update that label based on certain events. In one case, append the elapsed time in hours and minutes on that activity to the label. Thx

Comment: The why is because I didn't quite understand the question, just trying to get more context.

Comment: I have updated my question to be clearer about what I want to change. I am not wanting to change the Manifest, just that label as it appears in my activity, based on the XML Layout file I have shown. I can't figure out how to do that with my layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot add or remove or alter anything in the manifest as the name says, it's a manifest file, which system reads when it installs your app.

If you are just trying to change the title you can use:

If you are using `ActionBar`:

`getActionBar().setTitle(int titleId)`

If you are extending `AppCompatActivity`:

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle(int titleId)`

For example:

```
public class ChecklistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(...) {
        doMyTimerThing();
    }

    public void doMyTimerThing() {
       onTick(long timeLeft) {
           ...(long to string here)...
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle(timeToShowOnActionBar)
       }
    }
}
```

[Set Up the app bar Android Dev Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up).

[ActionBar vs SupportActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002209/android-getactionbar-vs-getsupportactionbar)

[ActionBar Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar)

This is a simple implementation, If you want to have more control you over your ActionBar as your app progresses then you can use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar). Toolbar has to be added to your XML.

Comment: Ok - if that is true, then question answered. I will need to add a widget to the layout specifically for this task. I did not know. Thx

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the title on the appBar?

Comment: Yes. Just wanting to change the ?appBar? title that shows on the screen. Can you show me some code that matches the XML I provided? I don't see actionBar in there. I have 'tabAppBarLayout', but that doesn't see to take a setTitle() method.

Comment: I see now how my question caused the confusion. That text I point out in the manifest file shows on my activity. I guess it is the appBar or AppBarLayout, or whatever, but that is where I want to change what is displayed.

Comment: Cool, I updated my answer, that sounds like it should work.

Comment: Richard, I don't have anything in my XML that says 'actionBar'. Sorry for being dense, but I need to know how to get there from my XML file (e.g. it started with the Studio template and I really don't understand this CoordinatorLayout at all).

Comment: Updated my answer to try to be more clear. You do not need to change your label in your manifest, and you can't you are just trying to change the title at runtime.

Comment: hey if you want to chane your action bar title name in activity only use getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "title" );

Comment: That's it guys! That is all I was after. Sorry I didn't explain it all so well in my question. Obviously part of the reason it was a mystery to me. I would prefer to get rid of the coordinatorlayout and go with something a bit more explicit like a constraintlayout. That will be my next task is to convert that XML layout into a constraintlayout.